# Make content type available for anonymous to edit and use front end theme

Tags: nodes, theming

I have a content type that I have made available for anonymous users to edit. I want that content type when it is in edit mode to use the front end theme. How would I achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure your anonymous user role (and any other relevant roles) don't have the 'View the administration theme' permission...then they'll get the default front-end theme when accessing any page that's deemed to be an 'admin' page.

[image]

Comment: is that in the normal permissions table? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: It's under **System**.  Just a little tidbit, [FPA](http://drupal.org/project/fpa) helps greatly when your permissions list gets long.  It's essentially [Module Filter](http://drupal.org/project/module_filter) but for the permissions page :)

Comment: Yep, it's under the System Module's permissions in Drupal 7. I don't think there's an equivalent for D6 in case you're using that, but you could use something like [ThemeKey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) to do the same thing.

Comment: On the off change you are on D6, I **think** the [Administration theme](http://drupal.org/project/admin_theme) module will allow the same functionality as D7 core.  I emphasise the **think** part as it's been a year or so since I've touched D6 in any great depth, and haven't had to use this in D7.

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunately a D6 site... Sorry I didn't mention that, but at least the question is now clear for both set ups! Thanks for the help.